$\frac{1}{2}$-Hölder surjective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$
Let $X\subset{\mathbb{R}^d}$ be bounded and let $f:X\rightarrow{}\mathbb{R}^d$ be an $\alpha$-Hölder map, that is to say:
$$\|f(x)-f(y)\|\le{}C\|x-y\|^{\alpha},\text{ for some }\alpha>0\text{ and some }C>0.$$
Now I want to see if there is a $\frac{1}{2}$-holder surjective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$. According to this article https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00009375, the best $\alpha$ we can get is $\frac{1}{3}$, which seems to be the answer here. However, I want to know if there is an easier way to check the existence of such a map.

Why do you start with a function defined on $X \subset \Bbb R^d$ if the real question is about $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3$?

@MartinR Thought it would be better to give a general definition

But your initial definition is about functions between sets of the same dimension $d$, but $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3$ is a function between sets of different dimensions.

$\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$
